# Merging multiple XML files into single file with different format

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have 1200+ XML in the same format that I need to merge into a single XML file of a different format.  The individual files are all located in a single directory.  The server I am working on has SimpleXML and I've tried using a few different merge examples I've found online (http://www.nicolaskuttler.com/post/merging-and-splitting-xml-files-with-simplexml/, for one), but when I view the 'merged' XML file, only the first XML file was added to it.  I have not been able to get more than one of the files to 'merge' with any of my several attempts.

Format of the individual files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pr:press_release xmlns:alf="http://www.alfresco.org" xmlns:chiba="http://chiba.sourceforge.net/xforms" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:pr="http://www.bowl.com/pr" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <pr:headline>TITLE</pr:headline>
        <pr:title>TITLE</pr:title>
        <pr:contact_info xsi:nil="true"/>
        <pr:department>DEPT</pr:department>
        <pr:body>BODY</pr:body>
        <pr:launch_date>YYYY-MM-DD</pr:launch_date>
        <pr:expiration_date>YYYY-MM-DD</pr:expiration_date>
        <pr:category>CATEGORY</pr:category>
        <pr:tags>KEYWORDS</pr:tags>
</pr:press_release>
```

Format needed for new file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contents>
  <content>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <summary></summary>
    <body>
      <root>
        <date></date>
        <author></author>
        <department></department>
        <location></location>
        <story>BODY</story>
      </root>
    </body>
  </content>
</contents>
```

Code used to merge two files:

```
<?php
        $file1 = '1027coachintermediate.xml';
        $file2 = '1027coachelite.xml';
        $fileout = 'fileout.xml';       $xml1 = simplexml_load_file( $file1 );
        $xml2 = simplexml_load_file( $file2 );  // loop through the FOO and add them and their attributes to xml1
        foreach( $xml2->FOO as $foo ) {
                $new = $xml1->addChild( 'FOO' , $foo );
                foreach( $foo->attributes() as $key => $value ) {
                        $new->addAttribute( $key, $value );
                }
        }       $fh = fopen( $fileout, 'w') or die ( "can't open file $fileout" );
        fwrite( $fh, $xml1->asXML() );
        fclose( $fh );
?>
```

Comment: can you give your xml-merge code?

Comment: I just added in the code I am using to merge two files - I have not yet determined how I will get all 1200 merged, but I figure I should at least understand how to merge two files before I try to attempt that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time task then you could concatenate all the files together and then run a simple XSLT process on the concatenated file.

1)  Shell script to concatenate files

```
for file in `ls $XMLDIR`
  do
        cat $file | grep -v "xml version" >> big_concat_file.xml
  done
```

2)  Hand edit concat file to put root wrapper tag.

```
<document>
   <pr:press-release>
       ....
   </pr:press-release>
   <pr:press-release>
       ...
   </pr:press-release>
</document>
```

3)  Run XSLT file on concatenated file

Answer (score 0):

No really sure where you made the error, but below is the script which should help you merge files according to specs:

```
<?php
$files = array( 'in1.xml', 'in2.xml');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contents>
</contents>
XML
);

foreach( $files as $filename) {
    $xml_int = simplexml_load_file( $filename );
    $conts = $xml_int->children('pr',true);
    $content = $xml->addChild( 'content'); // add content
    $content->addChild( 'title',$conts->title); // add first title
    // add the rest of the content insides
    // ...
}
var_export($xml->asXML());
?>
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>            
<contents><content><title>TITLE1</title></content><content><title>TITLE2</title></content></contents>
```

see: http://pl.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php for more info

The other question is if you really want to keep the whole xml in memory. You can just append the `$content->asXML()` one by one to the file.

Comment: I am needing to get the data from one CMS to another, and the old one made each piece of content its own file.  The new one wants one single file for importing.

Comment: The output will be one file, cos it\`s appended. I was only sugesting to not construct the `$xml` in memory.